# The argument type 'List<Series<dynamic, dynamic>>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List<Series<dynamic, String*>*>*'

Tags: flutter, charts

hello i got error in below code , on widget

The argument type 'List<Series<dynamic, dynamic>>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List<Series<dynamic, String*>>'.

and this my code

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    // ignore: import_of_legacy_library_into_null_safe
    import 'package:charts_flutter/flutter.dart' as charts;
    
    class SimpleBarChart extends StatelessWidget {
      final List<charts.Series> seriesList;
      final bool? animate;
    
      SimpleBarChart(this.seriesList, {this.animate});
    
      factory SimpleBarChart.withSampleData() {
        return new SimpleBarChart(
          _createSampleData(),
          // Disable animations for image tests.
          animate: false,
        );
      }
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return new charts.BarChart(
          seriesList, //error this
          animate: animate,
        );
      }
    
      /// Create one series with sample hard coded data.
      static List<charts.Series<OrdinalSales, String>> _createSampleData() {
        final data = [
          new OrdinalSales('2014', 5),
          new OrdinalSales('2015', 25),
          new OrdinalSales('2016', 100),
          new OrdinalSales('2017', 75),
        ];
    
        return [
          new charts.Series<OrdinalSales, String>(
            id: 'Sales',
            colorFn: (_, __) => charts.MaterialPalette.blue.shadeDefault,
            domainFn: (OrdinalSales sales, _) => sales.year,
            measureFn: (OrdinalSales sales, _) => sales.sales,
            data: data,
          )
        ];
      }
    }
    
    class OrdinalSales {
      final String year;
      final int sales;
    
      OrdinalSales(this.year, this.sales);
    }
}
```

Is my code not compatible with the chart plugin above?
how to solve this ?

Answer (score 2):

Change your  class from

```
class SimpleBarChart extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<charts.Series> seriesList;
  final bool animate;
```

To this

```
class SimpleBarChart extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<charts.Series<dynamic, String>> seriesList;
  final bool? animate;
```